# string compression counting the repeated character in javascript

Tags: javascript

If I have a string `a12c56a1b5` then out put should be `a13b5c56` as character `a` is repeated twice so `a12` becomes `a13`

I have tried this:

```
function stringCompression (str) {
  var output = '';
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    count++;
    if (str[i] != str[i+1]) {
      output += str[i] + count;
      count = 0;
    }
  }
  console.log(output); // but it returns `a11121c15161a111b151` instead of `a13b5c56`
}
```

Comment: Please add some more details regarding what you want to achieve and why the output should be what you have mentioned.

Comment: you're concatenating to a string, not adding to a number.  you need to extract the number (with substring or whatever), convert to a number, and then add, then reinsert it into the string.

Comment: @Tushar updated question

Comment: your code counts every char and counts it once, then adds the char and the count (always going to be 1).

Comment: Are you counting the "a"s (for example)?  If so, the "a"s count should be 2.  There is a "1" after the second "a" - shouldn't you add that to the "12" of the first "a"? - otherwise, why is there a "1"?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is happening because the code is counting the occurrence of each element and appending it, even the numbers in the string.

In this code,

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
count++;
    if (str[i] != str[i+1]) {
      output += str[i] + count;
      count = 0;
    }
}
```

in first iteration `i = 0`, `str[i] = 'a'` and `str[i + 1] = '1'` for the given string `a12c56a1b5` which are not equal hence, it will generate the output as `a1` for first iteration, then `a111` for second iteration since `str[i] = '1'` and `str[i + 1] = '2'` now, and so on.

We can achieve this by first separating the characters from the count. Assuming, that there would be characters from `a-z` and `A-Z` only followed by the count. We can do something like this, `str.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g)` to get the characters: `["a", "c", "a", "b"]` and `str.match(/[0-9]+/g)` to get their counts: `["12", "56", "1", "5"]`, put them in an object one by one and add if it already exists.

Something like this:

```js
function stringCompression(str) {
  var characters = str.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g);
  var counts = str.match(/[0-9]+/g);
  var countMap = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
    if (countMap[characters[i]]) {
      countMap[characters[i]] += parseInt(counts[i]);
    } else {
      countMap[characters[i]] = parseInt(counts[i]);
    }
  }
  var output = Object.keys(countMap)
                     .map(key => key + countMap[key])
                     .reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  console.log(output);
}
stringCompression('a12c56a1b5')
```

Comment: Your answer needs `parseInt(counts[i])`

Answer (score 3):

Using regex to extract word characters and numbers.  Keeps an object map `res` to track and sum up following numbers.  sorts and converts back to a string.

As an example, the for-of loop iteration flow with `str=a12c56a1b5`:

1. c='a', n='12'
   res['a'] = (+n = 12) + ( (res['a'] = undefined)||0  = 0)
   or ie: res['a'] = 12 + 0
2. c='c', n='56'
   res['c'] = 56 + 0
3. c='a', n='1'
   res['a'] = 1 + (res['a'] = 12 from iteration 1.) = 13
4. c='b', n='5'
   res['b'] = 5 + 0

thus `res = { 'a': 13, 'c': 56, 'b': 5 }` after the [for-of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop finishes

```js
function stringCompression (str) {
  // build object map with sums of following numbers
  const res = {}
  for(const [,c,n] of str.matchAll(/(\w+)(\d+)/g))
    res[c] = +n + (res[c]||0)
  
  // convert object map back to string
  output = Object.entries(res)
  output.sort(([a],[b])=>a<b ? -1 : a>b ? 1 : 0)
  output = output.map(([a,b])=>`${a}${b}`).join('')
  
  
  console.log(output); // but it returns `a11121c15161a111b151` instead of `a13b5c56`
}

stringCompression('a12c56a1b5')
```

`[,c,n] = [1,2,3]` is equivalent to c=2, n=3.  It is called [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

[`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) matches on a regex.  It's a relatively new shorthand for calling `.exec` repeatedly to execute a regular expression that collects all the results that the regular expression matches on.

`(\w+)(\d+)` is a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for two capture groups,
`\w+` is for one or more alpha characters, `\d+` is for one or more digits.

`for(const [,c,n] of str.matchAll...)` is equivalent to:

```
for each M of str.matchAll...
  const c = M[1], n = M[2]`
```

- `res[c]||0` is shorthand for:
  "give me `res[c]` if it is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) (not undefined, null or 0), otherwise give me `0`"
- `+n` uses the unary operator `+` to force an implicit conversion to a number.  JavaScript specs for `+` unary makes it convert to number, since `+` unary only makes sense with numbers.
  It is basically the same as using `Number(n)` to convert a string to an number.

Conversion back to a string:

- [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) converts an object `{"key":value}` to an array in the form of `[ [key1, value1], [key2, value2] ]`.  This allows manipulating the elements of an object like an array.
- [`.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) sorts the array. I destructured the keys to sort on the keys, so "a" "b" "c" are kept in order.
- [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) takes an array, and "maps" it to another array. In this case I've mapped each `[key,value]` to a string `key+value`, and then taking the final mapped array of `key+value` strings and joined them together to get the final output.

Comment: This parts are not clear ` [,c,n]` and `res[c] = +n + (res[c]||0)`

Answer (score 0):

In case it asks you to sort it alphabetically, I added [@user120242](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120242/user120242)'s sorting code snippet to [@saheb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2326172/saheb)'s entire answer (in between `Object.keys(countMap)` and `.map(...)`. That worked for me. I tried using [@user120242](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120242/user120242)'s whole answer, but it did not pass all the tests since it did not add the repeated letters for longer strings. But [@user120242](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120242/user120242)'s answer did work. It just need to be sorted alphabetically and it passed all the test cases in HackerRank. I had this question for a coding assessment (called "Better Coding Compression").

P.S. I also removed checking the capital letters from [@saheb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2326172/saheb)'s code since that wasn't required for my coding challenge.

Here's how mine looked like:

```js
function stringCompression(str) {
  var characters = str.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g);
  var counts = str.match(/[0-9]+/g);
  var countMap = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
    if (countMap[characters[i]]) {
      countMap[characters[i]] += parseInt(counts[i]);
    } else {
      countMap[characters[i]] = parseInt(counts[i]);
    }
  }
  var output = Object.keys(countMap)
                     .sort(([a],[b])=>a<b ? -1 : a>b ? 1 : 0)
                     .map(key => key + countMap[key])
                     .reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  console.log(output);
}
stringCompression('a12c56a1b5')
```